# Download file according to date

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this shell script :

```
#while true; do
#sleep 600
 echo "####Removing then Rebuilding###"
today=`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`
cd reports 
mongoexport --db=graphqlAmazonV2 --collection=purchasefromappobjectmodels   --type=csv  --fields=_id,receiptId,sku,itemType,UserData,purchaseDate,idfa,status --out=info.$today.csv 
#done
```

As it shows it exports data from the db and save as a .csv file.
I added the `$today` date so that i would know when was the csv file created.
Before that i had one csv `info.csv` file that was removed then exported again thus i was able to download easily using express built in file downloader.

```
const file = `${__dirname}/reports/info.csv`;
  console.log("downloading ... ");
  res.download(file);
```

Now the file doesnt have a fixed name , it changes and is named according of its date of initialization.

Example : `info.2021-02-04T20:10:02.csv`

How can i download now ? I thought of parsing the file name and compare with the now date then download.

step 2 : Download according to a filter `This question i will post later`

Answer (score -1):

To do such yo can use this :

```
router.post("/download", function (req, res) {
  var yourscript = exec("./export.sh", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log(stdout);
    console.log(stderr);
  });

  function downloadLatestFile() {
    const dirPath = "/Users/tarekhabche/Desktop/awsTest/reports";
    const lastFile = JSON.stringify(getMostRecentFile(dirPath));
    fileDate = lastFile.substr(14, 19);
    console.log(fileDate);
    const fileToDownload = `reports/info.${fileDate}.csv`;
    console.log(fileToDownload);
    res.download(fileToDownload);
  }
  setTimeout(function () {
    downloadLatestFile();
  }, 1000);
});

const getMostRecentFile = (dir) => {
  const files = orderRecentFiles(dir);
  return files.length ? files[0] : undefined;
};

const orderRecentFiles = (dir) => {
  return fs
    .readdirSync(dir)
    .filter((file) => fs.lstatSync(path.join(dir, file)).isFile())
    .map((file) => ({ file, mtime: fs.lstatSync(path.join(dir, file)).mtime }))
    .sort((a, b) => b.mtime.getTime() - a.mtime.getTime());
};

const dirPath = "reports";
getMostRecentFile(dirPath);
```